# How to fill textboxes on a website with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, internet-explorer, textbox, browser

I'm trying to use MATLAB to fill in textboxes on a webpage in Internet Explorer without typing directly into the URL. Can anyone explain to me how to do this? I'm pretty lost. I really appreciate any help you can give me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have seen this done before (i.e. running a MATLAB script that automatically fills in fields in Internet Explorer), to the best of my knowledge, I do not believe that there is an actual MATLAB command to directly interface with IE.

Instead, you can make use of the MATLAB command `system` to call an external program that actually does the interfacing with IE.

For example, you might be able to make a Visual Basic program that interfaces with IE through the InternetExplorer object.  I'm not too familiar with VB, but this [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might help.  Once you've created this program, use MATLAB's `system` command to execute it (passing command-line arguments to define what/how to fill in the textboxes).

Take a look at the doc for [system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/system.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it many times with a small program called [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).
With this program you can write a script, that will move the mouse / click the keyboard. you can pass string arguments and use it inside the script. once done, you can call this script from matlab.